# Force hyphenation of glossary term in-text

Tags: glossaries, hyphenation

In English, you sometimes want to add hyphens when the order of words can make the meaning ambiguous. Example:

Confusing:

```
 Springfield has little town charm.
```

Better:

```
 Springfield has little-town charm.
```

Now, let's say `little town` is defined in the glossary ([glossary](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary) package) without hyphen (because the term does not normally require it) and I want to insert it in the sentence above, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{little_town}
{
    name={little town},
    description={A town that is small}
}

\begin{document}
Springfield has \gls{little_town} charm.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

How can I tell latex to hyphenate the term `little town` in this specific sentence?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add your own field, and define the pattern in the entry definition.  You would still have to manually point to which gls entry you want to use, but I can't see latex running a grammar check to evaluate this part for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\glsaddkey
    {hyphenated}        % new key
    {\relax}            % default value if "hyphenated" isn't used in \newglossaryentry
    {\glsentryhyph}     % analogous to \glsentrytext
    {\Glsentryhyph}     % analogous to \Glsentrytext
    {\glshyph}          % analogous to \glstext
    {\Glshyph}          % analogous to \Glstext
    {\GLShyph}          % analogous to \GLStext

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{little_town}
{
    name={little town},
    hyphenated={little-town},
    description={A town that is small}
}

\begin{document}
Springfield has \glshyph{little_town} charm.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```